# Why can't I assign a shuffled array to a new array

Tags: dart

Why can't I assign a shuffled array to a new array?

For example, this is my list:

```
 List nums = [1, 2, 3];

List newlist=nums.shuffle();
```

However, this does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `shuffle()` on `List` does not return anything (which is indicated by `void` which means the method does not return anything usable) but are instead shuffling the list you are calling the method on.

> ```
> void shuffle([Random? random])
> ```
>
> Shuffles the elements of this list randomly.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/List/shuffle.html

If you want to output your `nums` list after it have been shuffled, you just need to print `nums` like this after the `nums.shuffle()` call:

```
void main() {
  final nums = [1, 2, 3];
  nums.shuffle();
  print(nums); // [2, 3, 1]
}
```

If you want to have a new list there is shuffled and based on another list, you can do something like this (the `..` is called a cascade call, you can read more about it here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation):

```
void main() {
  final nums = [1, 2, 3];
  final shuffeledNums = nums.toList()..shuffle();

  print(nums); // [1, 2, 3]
  print(shuffeledNums); // [2, 1, 3]
}
```

Which is the same as this without the use of cascade:

```
void main() {
  final nums = [1, 2, 3];
  final shuffeledNums = nums.toList();
  shuffeledNums.shuffle();

  print(nums); // [1, 2, 3]
  print(shuffeledNums); // [2, 1, 3]
}
```